# Was there a special prize for the 1,000th 10Ker?

Tags: discussion, unicorns, humor, fun

There are [953 10K rep people on SO, up 10 on last week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) - so I guess June 2011 will see the psychologically important 1000 SO 'super' user mark breached.

Aside from the bunting that is released from the ceiling of SO Towers when *every* new 10Ker is born - will there be a special prize for Mr or Mrs 1K/10K?

And if so what colour should the unicorn be as flights to Iceland are a bit tricky at the best of times?

**EDIT**

It appears *ahem* that Mr or Mrs 1K/10K has already been born, something or other to do with maths I think - can we at least speculate on what this mystery individual won for their efforts?

Comment: I'll punch them through the intertubes.  People love getting punched through the intertubes.

Comment: I'mma write a comment.  10kers love comments.

Comment: Lemme know who gets punched, when you figure it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your enthusiasm is infectious but I should point out that the number you are quoting:

- 953 10k rep people on 10

is actually the number of people currently greater than or equal to 10k **and** less than 25k, not the total number of users greater than or equal to 10k.

Sadly, the total number of 10k users has already passed 1,000 and is [currently 1,262](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow).

P.S.  Coincidentally, my ranking is 1,262.  :-)

Comment: Well that spoils things somewhat!

Answer (score 2):

Bragging rights.